# new machine and vs 2013, and .net 2.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013

I recently got a new machine and after installing vs2013 I tried working on an existing .net 2.0 project. It  is giving me errors for a library that I can see in the References.

In the references list, it also shows yellow signs next to some system libraries like:

```
System.Data.DataSetExtensions
System.Web.ApplicationServices
System.Web.DynamicData
System.Web.Entity
System.Web.Extensions
System.Xml.Linq
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Framework version...maybe you need to install it

Comment: I did install version 2.0

Comment: When you open the project, are you sure that Visual Studio didn't update the project to run with 4 or 4.5 framework?